# Facing an error when trying to insert the data in database using db2?

Tags: sql, db2

I'm trying to insert a row in the table by using below code but it is throwing an error. can anyone help me out to solve the error?

Thanks in advance!!

`db2 "Insert into TARIFF_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES values (409499, 'ADDITION_SMS_TEMPLATE', 'IDSSMS1')";`

Error is :

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
>   valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
>   SQL0204N  "DB2EAI2.TARIFF_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES" is an undefined name.
>   SQLSTATE=42704

Comment: Prefix your table with database. Example :- [database_name].TARIFF_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE. Check if this solves your issue. Also check if table TARIFF_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTE is already created in database.

Comment: Error says `DB2EAI2.TARIFF_PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES` so - I presume that it knows the database name, but it appears that table name is misspelled (or doesn't exist).

Answer (score 0):

Common causes of SQL0204N in Db2:

- spelling mistake in the object name
- object does not exist in the currently connected Db2 database
- object exists in current database but in a different *schema* than your current default schema  (so you must qualify the name with the correct schema-name).
- mixed case table name (Db2 will always uppercase unquoted object names, so if the object is Tariff_Product_Attributes then use double-quotes around the name in the SQL to allow Db2 to find the object).

There are other less common causes , see the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql00204n.html) for the complete list.